# @PrePersist error when saving child entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jackson, saga

I have a parent-child entity set up like this. The AuditEntity simply sets up some common fields for audit purposes (stuff like dateCreated, dateUpdated etc).

***Parent***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION")
@Audited()
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Application extends AuditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "appl_sequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "appl_sequence", sequenceName = "SEQ_APPL")
  private Long id;
  @Version
  private Long version;

  @Column(name = "APPL_TITLE")
  private String applicationTitle;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Subject> subjects;

}
```

***Child***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
@Audited()
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Subject extends AuditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "subj_sequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "subj_sequence", sequenceName = "SEQ_SUBJECT")
  private Long id;
  @Version
  private Long version;

  @Column(name = "SUBJ_TITLE")
  private String subjectTitle;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="APPL_ID")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Application application;
}
```

My first test was to insert an application without any child subjects.

```
{
    "id": null,
    "version": null,
    "action": "SUBMIT",
    "applicationTitle": "Candidate 1 application",
}


public void save(Application app) {
  applicationRepository.save(app);
}
```

This works fine, and I was able to successfully insert a record into the database. However once I added the subjects, I get a NullPointerException.

```
{
    "id": null,
    "version": null,
    "action": "SUBMIT",
    "applicationTitle": "Candidate 1 application",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 1"
        },
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 2"
        }
        ]
}
```

I have tried to debug the function and there does not appear to be any problem with the entity object. At the least I couldn't see any null values where it shouldn't be. I have even tried some roundabout solutions.

```
public void save(Application app) {
  List<Subject> subjects = app.getSubjects();
  app.setSubjects(null);
  applicationRepository.save(app); // this works once subjects is null
  // Method 2
  subjectRepository.saveAll(subjects); // doesn't work
  // Method 3
  for (Subject subject : subjects) {
    subjectRepository.save(subject); // doesn't work either
  }
}
```

All 3 of the methods gave me the same NullPointerException. The stacktrace points to a JpaRepository issue, but I'm not sure what I am missing.

EDIT: added stacktrace

```
2019-06-19T10:22:39,626 [36mERROR[m s.g.s.i.c.s.w.GlobalExceptionHandler:210 - unknown runtime exception caught
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at <removed>.OperationsBaseEntity.prePersist(OperationsBaseEntity.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.EntityCallback.performCallback(EntityCallback.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy251.save(Unknown Source)
    at <removed>.application.service.impl.ApplicationService.saveApplication(ApplicationService.java:210)
    at <removed>.application.service.impl.ApplicationService.insert(ApplicationService.java:126)
    at <removed>.application.controller.ApplicationController.create(ApplicationController.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-06-19T10:22:39,725 [36mWARN [m o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver:194 - Resolved exception caused by handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

EDIT 2: added the AuditEntity. These were set up by my seniors working on the framework, so I'm not entirely sure how they work yet (a lot of these tech is new to me). I'll definitely be talking to them about it though.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited()
public class AuditEntity extends OperationsBaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DT")
    private LocalDateTime createdDt;
    @Column(name = "DELETED_BY")
    private String deletedBy;
    @Column(name = "DELETED_DT")
    private LocalDateTime deletedDt;
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DT")
    private LocalDateTime updatedDt;
}

@Audited()
@MappedSuperclass
public class OperationsBaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 30)
    private String status;

    @ColumnDefault("1")
    @Column(name = "IS_SAGA_IN_PROGRESS", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isSagaInProgress;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ACTION", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private ACTION action;

    @PrePersist // is this what's causing the issues?
    public void prePersist() {
        if (Objects.isNull(getIsSagaInProgress())) {
            isSagaInProgress = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        status = action.getStatus();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        if (Objects.isNull(getIsSagaInProgress())) {
            isSagaInProgress = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        status = action.getStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Always include the stacktrace if you have a question with an exception

Comment: Since the error is `prePersist` I would assume the error is due to the `AuditEntity` base class.

Comment: Looks like null `action` field in `prePersist`.

Comment: Okay, but why though? Why is @PrePersist triggering a null pointer in a child entity, but not its parents? And how do I resolve, or at the very least, work around it temporarily?

Comment: @sml485 In fact this is puzzles me as well. I’ve just noticed that both entities are mapped to the same table. Is that expected? The entities use different sequences for id.

Comment: Oh damn sorry, that was a bad copy-pasta when I was writing the question. I've corrected the entities. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Enable the SQL logging and see what happens/inserted when you only insert the parent without children?  Something somewhere must be setting `action` which isn't in any of the code you've shown us thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, huge thanks to @K.Nicholas, @Lesiak and @Naros for pointing me in the right direction.

Yes the problem is with my ACTION attribute. What I failed to present in my original question (which I've since corrected) was that I had `action` set in my parent entity, but not my child. I just assumed it would auto propagate down.

For context, the ACTION enum is used to determine user action ("SUBMIT", "APPROVE" etc.) and therefore the status of the record after the action is successfully executed. Apparently this is part of how the [Saga design pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) works.

So instead of

```
{
    "id": null,
    "version": null,
    "action": "SUBMIT",
    "applicationTitle": "Candidate 1 application",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 1"
        },
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 2"
        }
        ]
}
```

I need to manually set the actions for all child entities as well.

```
{
    "id": null,
    "version": null,
    "action": "SUBMIT",
    "applicationTitle": "Candidate 1 application",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 1",
            "action": "SUBMIT"
        },
        {
            "subjectTitle": "Subject 2",
            "action": "SUBMIT"
        }
        ]
}
```

This allows me to save both parent and child entities with a single `.save()` call to the parent repository.